# Padding text with ellipsis if it's too long

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to solve a jQuery problem. I'm using a wordpress plugin that creates a widget from recent posts. The plugin auto-generates some code that I'm sort-of trying to format/hack with CSS and jQuery. One of the items that is auto generated is a headline:

```
<h4 class="srp-post-tilte">HEADLINE HERE</H4>
```

My design depends on this headline not exceeding a given length. (about 45 characters). The plugin provides an option to add an elipsis after the headline for this very issue (I set it to 45 characters). The problem is that when the headline is under 45 characters the elipses still show up.

So, I've turned off the feature and am trying to do it in jQuery. I'd only like to add an elipsis in situations where the headline is cropped to 45 characters. I tried this, but it's not working.

```
if ($j("h4.srp-post-title").val().length > 44) { 
         // Show the elipsis
            $j('h4.srp-post-title').append("...");
} else {
         // Don's show the elipsis (do nothing)
        $j('h4.srp-post-title').append("");
}
```

If anyone out there can help, it would be very much appreciated. You can see a live example at http://dreamlets.sfplanning.org/ but be forewarned, there is a lot of CSS therein, so it may be tricky to decipher what's going on under the hood.

Comment: `<h4 class="srp-post-tilte">` is `"tilte"` a typo?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using `text-overflow: ellipsis;`?

```
.srp-post-tilte {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I try it on chrome and I don't see any problem!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

```
var header = $('h4.srp-post-title').text();
if( $('h4.srp-post-title').text().length > 45 )
    $('h4.srp-post-title').html(header.substring(0,45) + '&hellip;');
```

<kbd>[**Working example**](http://jsbin.com/ojuyax/1/edit)</kbd>

---

#### Explaination

**First there is a API usage mistake**. Use the `text()` method instead of the `val()` one to get what you need. That is:

```
$j("h4.srp-post-title").text().length
```

instead of

```
$j("h4.srp-post-title").val().length
```

`val()` just gets the `value` attribute of an element, mostly used to grab values from `input` fields.

**Also, append the HTML entity `&hellip;`** (instead of the three dots) because it is the correct character you are looking for.

I also noticed **you weren't trimming at all**, which I don't know whether it is because it was just an example or not. In any case, you will have to do something like I mentioned above to trim your text.

Basically what you do is check if the title is longer than 45 characters, then use the `substring` string method to get the first 45 characters and add an ellipsis. Voilà.

---

By the way, it might be a better option to modify the way the plugin works, it shouldn't be that difficult. In the end, your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to cut part of the text off, and then apply the ellipsis, like so:

```
$j("h4.srp-post-title").text(function(i, txt) {
    return txt.substring(0,42) + (txt.length > 45 ? '...' : '');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wHQ9W/)

Answer (score 0):

I authored a plugin that does this (and more!) called ellipsify.

You'd use it like this:

```
$j("h4.srp-post-title").ellipsify({
    count: 45
});
```

https://github.com/ethagnawl/ellipsify